# Can GMod/SFM models be converted to Unity GameObjects?

Tags: unity, file-format, steam, compatibility

Someone made a suite of [GMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry%27s_Mod)/[SFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Filmmaker) models available for free for people making games and videos in GMod and SFM. These are of type `.dmx`, `.dx80.vtx`, `.dx90.vtx`, `.mdl`, `.phy`, `.sw.vtx`, `.vvd`, `.vmt`, and `.vtf`. I don't use GMod or SFM, so I don't know what these are, thus making it hard for me to manually convert them. **Is there any way to change these into files Unity can recognize and use?**

I'd like to have an easy step from converting them, but I would also accept instructions on how to export them to generic mesh/skeleton/texture files, and then how to import and combine these in Unity.

Comment: You might want to load these up in their native application (Hammer? I'm not sure) and try exporting them to a standard format.

Comment: if you know how to do this, could you post instructions as an answer?

Comment: My comment is the extent of my knowledge about this topic. I haven't used GMod or SFM before. I'm just suggesting you use a program that knows those formats as well as a format that Unity knows. If A can't talk to B, you need to have a translator that knows both A and B to convert between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nem's tool called [Crafty](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?p=45) to export to .OBJ, then just throw it into your pipeline like any other model.

Comment: It got the mesh to Unity fine, but the textures were lost... :/

Comment: You have to fully configure Crafty to point to your steam install, and you have to have loaded the models in-game to make sure steam actually has the data.

Answer (score 0):

Studiocompiler can decompile models to *.smd so you can import them into your fav 3d app with smd plugin.
The textures are saved in *.vtf format, you can open them with paint.net/gimp/photoshop + vtf-import/export plugin.